# Qt + VS2010: The program can't start because <xyz>.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I have created a visual studio 2010 solution from the following .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE    = app
CONFIG      += qt yyy zzz debug_and_release
TARGET  = XYZdepth

INCLUDEPATH += .

#HEADERS     = 
SOURCES  = main.cpp xyzMainWidget.cpp

yyy {
        LIBS += $(YYY_DIR)/release/yyy.lib
        INCLUDEPATH += $(YYY_DIR)
}

zzz {
    LIBS += $(ZZZ_DIR)/lib/x86/ZZZ.lib
    INCLUDEPATH += $(ZZZ_DIR)/inc

}
```

Of course, I've replaced some key words in there. It references yyy.lib, which has a corresponding DLL: yyy.dll.

I can compile XYZdepth in release mode, but when I run it it says:

```
The program can't start because yyy.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

Can anyone help with this? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You likely need to copy the DLLs in question to the folder your executable is in, or ensure that the DLLs are located in a folder in the system's PATH.

Comment: That kinda got it working - now however, I am getting the following error when I run the program:

"The procedure entry point ??4QPixmap@@QAEAAV0@$$QAV0@@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library QtGui4.dll"

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors, I fixed mine without copying over `.dll`. In the main project, go to properties -> build events -> post-build events -> command line. Put everything (xcopy..) on different lines, with first line having `start xco...` at the front. :)